# Squid3 Reverse Proxy - Force Cache and Suppress Version

Tags: vpn, cache, squid, pfsense, reverse-proxy

I have been using pfSense for about 2 years now and I love it. One of my favorite features has come to be Squid2 and Squid3. Right now I am using Squid3 to run both proxy and reverse proxy.

There are two questions if have to make it work perfectly:

**1. How can I force Squid3 (the reverse proxy part in pfSense) to suppress the addition headers identifying the host as Squid?** (picture of my headers attached.[Contained in the red box])

[image: Reverse Proxy Headers]

**2. How can I get Squid (reverse proxy) to forcefully cache static (text/HTML) content?**

Squid3 will query my web server on the local network every time I connect. I have two remote machines that I use for testing. When I look in my Squid logs both machines show their remote IP address separately and each time it says "TCP_MISS/200". (Picture attached)

I have a openVPN connection between two networks. One network is the public IP(site B) I use to run my website and the other network is my private network(site A). It works right now and the DNS has no problems resolving.

When i check the headers (in my example[contained in blue box]) it says that is has not changed for two days and has an eTag. That header is from Apache server itself(I have checked headers on localhost using [curl -I]).

If I understand how the reverse proxy is supposed to be working. Since it is being presented with a not changed since date it should be caching it at (site B), but instead it queries (site A) for each call.

[image: Proxy Event List]

**tl;dr - Need help suppressing Squid's headers in reverse proxy mode and forcing the reverse proxy to cache static content.**

I thank you for any assistance you can provide!

Comment: You should probably make #2 a separate question.

Comment: From what I van understand about the situation. The two are connected.